# Process responding freezing application

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I'm trying to detect if process is responding, and I'm doing it with System.Diagnostics

But the problem is when the process is not responding my form freezes, it should show message box with No in it but it just freezes while if the process is active it displays Yes as it should.

This is what I've done so far:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("Anticheat");

    foreach (Process p in processes)
    {
        if (p.Responding)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Yes");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No");
        }
    }
}
```

And yeah I'm checking it with a timer that runs every 5 seconds.

Comment: What do you get if you console.log() something before the `if (p.Responding)` line?

Comment: Am i correct in assuming that you have background workers? If you don't, it's only a little more work and will free up your main form so that it is always responding. [Check MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Also, from MSDN:
'If a process has a user interface, the Responding property contacts the user interface to determine whether the process is responding to user input. If the interface does not respond immediately, the Responding property returns false. Use this property to determine whether the interface of the associated process has stopped responding.

If the process does not have a MainWindowHandle, this property returns true.'
Does the process in question have a UI, and how do you know it isn't responding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A workaround will be to use task with a max wait timeout for getting the response

```
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("Anticheat");
        foreach (var p in processes)
        {

            var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => p.Responding);

            const int maxWaitForResponse = 1000; //ms
            var processResponding = task.Wait(maxWaitForResponse) && task.Result;

            MessageBox.Show(processResponding ? "Yes" : "No");
        }
    }
```